# How can I integrate Mod Security Rule Check in my custom java application

Tags: java, http, tomcat, mod-security, mod-security2

I am writing a java application which gets the http logs in json format string from servers like tomcat.

I want to check those http request/response pairs against mod-security rules for auditing-purposes.

I went through this link - https://www.trustwave.com/Resources/SpiderLabs-Blog/ModSecurity-for-Java---BETA-Testers-Needed/

Similar kinds of links I got for Apache Web Server, Nginx and IIS Servers.

But my problem is - I don't have access to Web Server, I have just http logs with all required information.

Can I integrate mod_security library using JNI/JNA to my custom java application and make it work with my custom formatted input??

Above link shows mod_security classes write logs to tomcat logs.

Is there any way to redirect mod-security event logs to some database like redis or elasticsearch or maybe logstash using some configuration??

Comment: It looks like this project is intended to be run directly within a web application as a `Filter` and not as a separate daemon/watchdog process. If you are producing a log file, maybe you want to look into something like `fail2ban`?

Comment: Yes I completely understand what you said. But again, I don't have control over Tomcat. I will get http logs from tomcat on which I have to execute modsecurity rules checking. I am wondering if I can write that stack on my own in java using libmodsecJNI.so.

Comment: Can anybody comment on using standalone codes of modsecurity writing a custom C/C++ wrapper over it?